# How to determine the number of levels between upper and lower level?

Tags: php

I have a function `checkLevel($upper,$lower)`. Suppose I pass `checkLevel(2,4)`. Now 2 is the parent of 3 and 3 is the parent of 4. The gap between them is of **2**. Similarly, if I enter `checkLevel(1,4)`, the result should be **3** because 1 is the parent of 2, 2 is the parent of 3 and 3 is the parent of 4. The number of levels are 3. Please see the image below. Can any one help me out?

[image]

Comment: show us what you have tried so far

Comment: Give us something to work from.... and as i see it you can just subtract the numbers from each other. If the parentid's are sequential and never broken out of pattern.

Comment: Well it is not sequential and as far as what I have done? The truth is that i've been brainstorming for all day and I have came up with nothing. That was the reason I wanted some sort of head start from you people. All I know is that a recursive function will be used.

Comment: if the levels are hierarchical structure, then just use a any tree traversal algorithm. If it can contain loops... then most likely your structure is wrong :) but still its possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work.

```
$level = 0;
function checkLevel($start,$end)
{
    global $level;
    $level++;
    $array = array(0=>array('id'=>1,'parent_id'=>'0','test'=>'a'),1=>array('id'=>2,'parent_id'=>'1','test'=>'b'),2=>array('id'=>3,'parent_id'=>'2','test'=>'c'),3=>array('id'=>4,'parent_id'=>'3','test'=>'d'));
    $key = array_search($end,array_column($array, 'id'));

    if($key == $start)
        return;
    else
        checkLevel($start,$key);
    //echo $key;exit;

}

checkLevel(2,4);
echo $level;
```

Comment: Here is a good article about the global variables and why is bad using them: http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?GlobalVariablesAreBad

Comment: Why are we declaring an array? Can't it be done without hard coating?

Comment: yeah we can instead of declaring array you should use your variable there.

Comment: Please accecpt this as answer if find it useful.